# EM algorithm help - Plot of expectation

Tags: expectation-maximization

Can someone plot an expectation of a function and show me how maximizing it = maximizing the lower bound of its likelihood in the EM algorithm ? I don't know how to plot the expectation of a function since the expectation gives me a number. How do i get a plot ?

http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/v26/n8/extref/nbt1406-S1.pdf

Comment: EM usually traverses the Maximum Likelihood of some random variables. The plot you have there is the log-scaled likelihood of the data given the parameters. Recall that $L(\theta|x)=P(x|\theta)$.

Comment: You are right that the expectation is a constant in terms of the random variables integrated over, but remains a function of the parameters $\theta$.  Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138800/expectation-maxmisation-algorithm-increases-true-likelihood-at-each-iteration/139633#139633

Comment: Thanks ! After reading through some notes online I found out that the expectation involved in the EM algorithm is actually the conditional expectation $ E [ f(x) | \theta ] $. I have gone through the coin toss example and i understand it. I am able to visualize what EM does at every step. What I am left with is again.... the equation of the E step. Is there any link that shows the PLOT of the expectation with varying theta ?

Comment: I know what the M step does, it repositions the mean but I still don't understand the equations involved. But what does it mean to maximize the equation of the expectation ? What does it mean when my expectation is in terms of a variable ? Someone please show me an ACTUAL plot of the expectation with varying theta ! Arrrghhhh !!

Comment: For example, if I have a gaussian distribution, its expectation is only a single value right ? How do I get multiple expectations like the plot you drew in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138800/expectation-maxmisation-algorithm-increases-true-likelihood-at-each-iteration?lq=1 ?

Comment: OH, is it if I set the mean of the gaussian as a variable then my expectation becomes a variable ? And so i can MAXIMIZE my expectation by differentiating it wrt. the the mean like in EM ?

Comment: 1) I randomly choose 2 points as the center of the 2 gaussians for 2 components
2) Then I find the likelihood of every point being in class A or B
3) Then I compute the mean based on the calculated probabilities of each point - which is equivalent to maximizing the expectation wrt. the mean
4) Repeat 2 and 3 until the mean doesn't change much

I think I have gotten it right !